# Using Spring MVC with html

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

Previously, I have used Spring MVC only with jsp files. And everything worked just fine. But today I tried to use an html file for the first time and immediately got into a trouble. For some reason, the content of html file is never displayed in my browser. Below is the configuration.

Config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("newTestPackage")
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

Hello World

</body>
</html>
```

Project structure:
[image: Structure]

What the browser displays:
[image: In browser]

JSP version works fine.
I don't understand why jsp page gets found and displayed and html one doesn't (status 'not found')

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? (If not, use Spring Boot.) With Boot, you will generally put your templates in `src/main/resources/templates`.

Comment: Yes, I do. And with index.html removed to src/main/resources/templates the result is the same

Comment: Well, what I found is that html works fine with usual Spring MVC configuration that doesn't involve Spring Boot. But combiining html and Spring Boot still remains a mistery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, spring boot serves the `static` resources from `src/main/resources/static` folder, so place your `index.html` inside that folder.

You can refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) on how Spring boot serves the static content for the web application.